# Varrer String em Busca de Substrings Ignorando Acentuação e Case e Para Cada Match Executar Uma Ação

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, regex, substring

Preciso buscar em uma string uma substring específica e para cada ocorrência encontrada, devo executar uma ação de substituir o que foi escrito pela versão em negrito, conforme consta na lista, ignorando acentuação e case.

**Exemplo:**

Possuo a lista com os itens:

- Arroz
- Batata ao Cheff
- Macarrão ao Molho
- Salmão

A cada letra digitada sugestões dos itens da lista irão aparecer para o usuário poder selecionar(typeahead), será ignorada a acentuação e será caso insensitivo.

Caso o usuário digite "ão" ou "ao", os seguintes itens devem ser sugeridos:

- Batata **ao** Cheff
- Macarr**ão** **ao** Molho
- Salm**ão**

A lista é retornada conforme as regras, mas o texto em negrito é devido a funcão `highlighter`, porém quando digito "ao" ele não ignora o acento e deixa em negrito apenas o que for 100% igual ao digitado. No caso "Macarrão ao Molho", fica ou "Macarr**ão** ao Molho" ou "Macarrão **ao** Molho", preciso que sejam as duas ocorrências.

Eu acredito que preciso varrer a string em busca dessa substring e verificar em todas as possíveis acentuações, caso execute um match eu preciso efetuar o replace do texto `ão` e `ao` por **ão** e **ao**, porém não consigo chegar em nível de código nessa solução.

**Highlighter**:

```js
//Item é o texto da lista, ex: "Macarrão ao Molho"
//Query é o que foi digitado pelo usuário
//Match é a porção do texto que é igual ao que foi digitado pelo usuário
    function Highlighter(item) {
            var query = $("#ReasonDescription").val().replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
            return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
                return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
            })
        },
```

**Matcher**

```js
function Matcher(value) {
    var accented = {
        'A': '[Aa\xaa\xc0-\xc5\xe0-\xe5\u0100-\u0105\u01cd\u01ce\u0200-\u0203\u0226\u0227\u1d2c\u1d43\u1e00\u1e01\u1e9a\u1ea0-\u1ea3\u2090\u2100\u2101\u213b\u249c\u24b6\u24d0\u3371-\u3374\u3380-\u3384\u3388\u3389\u33a9-\u33af\u33c2\u33ca\u33df\u33ff\uff21\uff41]',
        'B': '[Bb\u1d2e\u1d47\u1e02-\u1e07\u212c\u249d\u24b7\u24d1\u3374\u3385-\u3387\u33c3\u33c8\u33d4\u33dd\uff22\uff42]',
        'C': '[Cc\xc7\xe7\u0106-\u010d\u1d9c\u2100\u2102\u2103\u2105\u2106\u212d\u216d\u217d\u249e\u24b8\u24d2\u3376\u3388\u3389\u339d\u33a0\u33a4\u33c4-\u33c7\uff23\uff43]',
        'D': '[Dd\u010e\u010f\u01c4-\u01c6\u01f1-\u01f3\u1d30\u1d48\u1e0a-\u1e13\u2145\u2146\u216e\u217e\u249f\u24b9\u24d3\u32cf\u3372\u3377-\u3379\u3397\u33ad-\u33af\u33c5\u33c8\uff24\uff44]',
        'E': '[Ee\xc8-\xcb\xe8-\xeb\u0112-\u011b\u0204-\u0207\u0228\u0229\u1d31\u1d49\u1e18-\u1e1b\u1eb8-\u1ebd\u2091\u2121\u212f\u2130\u2147\u24a0\u24ba\u24d4\u3250\u32cd\u32ce\uff25\uff45]',
        'F': '[Ff\u1da0\u1e1e\u1e1f\u2109\u2131\u213b\u24a1\u24bb\u24d5\u338a-\u338c\u3399\ufb00-\ufb04\uff26\uff46]',
        'G': '[Gg\u011c-\u0123\u01e6\u01e7\u01f4\u01f5\u1d33\u1d4d\u1e20\u1e21\u210a\u24a2\u24bc\u24d6\u32cc\u32cd\u3387\u338d-\u338f\u3393\u33ac\u33c6\u33c9\u33d2\u33ff\uff27\uff47]',
        'H': '[Hh\u0124\u0125\u021e\u021f\u02b0\u1d34\u1e22-\u1e2b\u1e96\u210b-\u210e\u24a3\u24bd\u24d7\u32cc\u3371\u3390-\u3394\u33ca\u33cb\u33d7\uff28\uff48]',
        'I': '[Ii\xcc-\xcf\xec-\xef\u0128-\u0130\u0132\u0133\u01cf\u01d0\u0208-\u020b\u1d35\u1d62\u1e2c\u1e2d\u1ec8-\u1ecb\u2071\u2110\u2111\u2139\u2148\u2160-\u2163\u2165-\u2168\u216a\u216b\u2170-\u2173\u2175-\u2178\u217a\u217b\u24a4\u24be\u24d8\u337a\u33cc\u33d5\ufb01\ufb03\uff29\uff49]',
        'J': '[Jj\u0132-\u0135\u01c7-\u01cc\u01f0\u02b2\u1d36\u2149\u24a5\u24bf\u24d9\u2c7c\uff2a\uff4a]',
        'K': '[Kk\u0136\u0137\u01e8\u01e9\u1d37\u1d4f\u1e30-\u1e35\u212a\u24a6\u24c0\u24da\u3384\u3385\u3389\u338f\u3391\u3398\u339e\u33a2\u33a6\u33aa\u33b8\u33be\u33c0\u33c6\u33cd-\u33cf\uff2b\uff4b]',
        'L': '[Ll\u0139-\u0140\u01c7-\u01c9\u02e1\u1d38\u1e36\u1e37\u1e3a-\u1e3d\u2112\u2113\u2121\u216c\u217c\u24a7\u24c1\u24db\u32cf\u3388\u3389\u33d0-\u33d3\u33d5\u33d6\u33ff\ufb02\ufb04\uff2c\uff4c]',
        'M': '[Mm\u1d39\u1d50\u1e3e-\u1e43\u2120\u2122\u2133\u216f\u217f\u24a8\u24c2\u24dc\u3377-\u3379\u3383\u3386\u338e\u3392\u3396\u3399-\u33a8\u33ab\u33b3\u33b7\u33b9\u33bd\u33bf\u33c1\u33c2\u33ce\u33d0\u33d4-\u33d6\u33d8\u33d9\u33de\u33df\uff2d\uff4d]',
        'N': '[Nn\xd1\xf1\u0143-\u0149\u01ca-\u01cc\u01f8\u01f9\u1d3a\u1e44-\u1e4b\u207f\u2115\u2116\u24a9\u24c3\u24dd\u3381\u338b\u339a\u33b1\u33b5\u33bb\u33cc\u33d1\uff2e\uff4e]',
        'O': '[Oo\xba\xd2-\xd6\xf2-\xf6\u014c-\u0151\u01a0\u01a1\u01d1\u01d2\u01ea\u01eb\u020c-\u020f\u022e\u022f\u1d3c\u1d52\u1ecc-\u1ecf\u2092\u2105\u2116\u2134\u24aa\u24c4\u24de\u3375\u33c7\u33d2\u33d6\uff2f\uff4f]',
        'P': '[Pp\u1d3e\u1d56\u1e54-\u1e57\u2119\u24ab\u24c5\u24df\u3250\u3371\u3376\u3380\u338a\u33a9-\u33ac\u33b0\u33b4\u33ba\u33cb\u33d7-\u33da\uff30\uff50]',
        'Q': '[Qq\u211a\u24ac\u24c6\u24e0\u33c3\uff31\uff51]',
        'R': '[Rr\u0154-\u0159\u0210-\u0213\u02b3\u1d3f\u1d63\u1e58-\u1e5b\u1e5e\u1e5f\u20a8\u211b-\u211d\u24ad\u24c7\u24e1\u32cd\u3374\u33ad-\u33af\u33da\u33db\uff32\uff52]',
        'S': '[Ss\u015a-\u0161\u017f\u0218\u0219\u02e2\u1e60-\u1e63\u20a8\u2101\u2120\u24ae\u24c8\u24e2\u33a7\u33a8\u33ae-\u33b3\u33db\u33dc\ufb06\uff33\uff53]',
        'T': '[Tt\u0162-\u0165\u021a\u021b\u1d40\u1d57\u1e6a-\u1e71\u1e97\u2121\u2122\u24af\u24c9\u24e3\u3250\u32cf\u3394\u33cf\ufb05\ufb06\uff34\uff54]',
        'U': '[Uu\xd9-\xdc\xf9-\xfc\u0168-\u0173\u01af\u01b0\u01d3\u01d4\u0214-\u0217\u1d41\u1d58\u1d64\u1e72-\u1e77\u1ee4-\u1ee7\u2106\u24b0\u24ca\u24e4\u3373\u337a\uff35\uff55]',
        'V': '[Vv\u1d5b\u1d65\u1e7c-\u1e7f\u2163-\u2167\u2173-\u2177\u24b1\u24cb\u24e5\u2c7d\u32ce\u3375\u33b4-\u33b9\u33dc\u33de\uff36\uff56]',
        'W': '[Ww\u0174\u0175\u02b7\u1d42\u1e80-\u1e89\u1e98\u24b2\u24cc\u24e6\u33ba-\u33bf\u33dd\uff37\uff57]',
        'X': '[Xx\u02e3\u1e8a-\u1e8d\u2093\u213b\u2168-\u216b\u2178-\u217b\u24b3\u24cd\u24e7\u33d3\uff38\uff58]',
        'Y': '[Yy\xdd\xfd\xff\u0176-\u0178\u0232\u0233\u02b8\u1e8e\u1e8f\u1e99\u1ef2-\u1ef9\u24b4\u24ce\u24e8\u33c9\uff39\uff59]',
        'Z': '[Zz\u0179-\u017e\u01f1-\u01f3\u1dbb\u1e90-\u1e95\u2124\u2128\u24b5\u24cf\u24e9\u3390-\u3394\uff3a\uff5a]'
    };

    var pattern = function (query) {
        var words = query.replace(/([|()[{.+*?^$\\])/g, '\\$1').split(/\s+/);

        words.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.length - a.length;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = words[i].replace(/\S/g, function (character) {
                return accented[character.toUpperCase()] || character;
            });
        }
        return new RegExp(words.join("|"), 'g');
    };

    return value.match(pattern(value));
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso. Preciso chamar o replace para substituir "ão" e "ao" por suas versões em negrito.

Comment: Fiz este pequeno código que quem sabe pode dar alguma ideia: https://jsfiddle.net/h1gpea5v/

Answer (score 3):

A ideia básica é pegar o que foi digitado e fazer a busca desconsiderando os acentos e as diferenças entre maiúsculas e minúsculas. Depois, para cada ocorrência que for encontrada, você quebra o texto entre antes e depois do trecho buscado, além do próprio trecho (dentro da tag `strong`).

Segue o código, e mais abaixo, a - longa - explicação:

```js
const itens = [ 'Arroz', 'Batata ao Cheff', 'Macarrão ao Molho', 'Salmão' ];

function buscarItens(e) {
    const res = document.querySelector('#resultado ul');
    res.innerHTML = ''; // limpa os resultados

    const busca = e.target.value.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}/ug, ''); // o que foi digitado e deve ser buscado (removendo os acentos)
    const regex = new RegExp(busca.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'ig');
    for (const item of itens) { // para cada item do menu
        const text = item.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}/ug, '');
        let i = 0;
        const li = document.createElement('li'); // cria o elemento que terá o texto com highlight
        for (const match of text.matchAll(regex)) { // verificar todas as ocorrências da busca
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.slice(i, match.index))); // texto antes da palavra encontrada

            i = match.index + busca.length;
            let strong = document.createElement('strong');
            strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.slice(match.index, i))); // palavra destacada (a "busca")
            li.appendChild(strong);
        }
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.slice(i))); // texto depois da palavra
        if (li.childElementCount != 0) { // se encontrou algo, adiciona nos resultados
            res.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}

// cada vez que digitar algo no input, faz a busca
document.querySelector('#busca').addEventListener('input', buscarItens);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="busca">

<div id="resultado">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

## Remover acentos

Primeiro eu pego o que foi digitado e removo os acentos:

```js
const busca = e.target.value.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}/ug, '');
```

O funcionamento do método `normalize` é explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), mas para resumir, uma letra acentuada, como o `á` (letra `a` com acento agudo), segundo o Unicode, pode ser representada de duas maneiras:

1. composta - como o code point [U+00E1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1) (á)
2. decomposta - como uma combinação de dois code points (nesta ordem):

   - a letra "a" (sem acento): [U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061)
   - o acento agudo: [U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301)

<sup>E para entender o que é um code point, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).</sup>

A primeira forma é chamada NFC, e a segunda, NFD. Portanto, o código acima primeiro normaliza a string para NFD, "quebrando" os acentos em dois caracteres: a letra sem acento e o próprio acento.

Depois o `replace` usa o [*Unicode Property Escape*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes) `\p{M}`, que pega todos os caracteres das categorias "Mark" (são todas que começam com "M" [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Todos os acentos se encaixam nesta categoria, e como eu faço o `replace` para `''` (string vazia), na prática é o mesmo que remover os acentos. Ou seja, se a string for `ão`, ela se torna `ao`.

Vale lembrar que para o *Unicode Property Escape* funcionar, precisa da *flag* `u` (é a letra `u` depois das barras, [ver aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052) para mais detalhes), e atualmente já [possui um bom suporte da maioria dos *browsers*](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Unicode_Property_Escapes). Também uso a *flag* `g` para que ele substitua todas as ocorrências (sem esta *flag*, ele só substitui a primeira).

---

## Construir a regex para a busca

No próximo trecho:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(busca.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'ig');
```

Na string de busca (que já teve os acentos removidos no passo anterior), eu faço `replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')`. Isso serve para sanitizar a string, já que ela será usada posteriormente para construir uma regex (expressão regular). E como esta regex será construída a partir de algo digitado pelo usuário, deve-se tomar cuidado com os [meta-caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) (caracteres que possuem significado especial e precisam ser escapados com `\`). Este `replace` é explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052) (e neste link também tem outros pontos que se aplicam ao seu caso, sobre construir regex a partir de entradas do usuário - sugiro que leia).

Por fim, eu crio a regex usando o construtor de `RegExp`, que recebe a string com os meta-caracteres escapados e as *flags* `i` (*case insensitive*) e `g` (procura todas as ocorrências).

---

## A busca

Na busca, eu pego o nome do item e também removo os acentos, da mesma forma feita com a string de busca:

```js
const text = item.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}/ug, '');
```

Depois eu percorro todos os *matches* que a regex encontrar (`for (const match of text.matchAll(regex))`), e para cada trecho encontrado eu pego o texto que está antes dele, o próprio trecho encontrado (colocando-o dentro da tag `strong`) e o trecho que vem depois.

Vale lembrar que se for encontrada mais de uma ocorrência, todas são colocadas dentro de uma tag `strong`. Por exemplo:

[image: busca "ão"]

Repare que eu digitei "ão", e no caso do "Macarrão ao Molho" o resultado ficou "Macarr**ão** **ao** Molho" (tanto o "ão" quanto o "ao") foram trocados.

Se você só quer trocar uma ocorrência, ficaria diferente. Precisaria retirar a *flag* `g` e trocar `matchAll` por `match` (e não usar um `for`, já que o retorno é somente um resultado):

```js
const itens = [ 'Arroz', 'Batata ao Cheff', 'Macarrão ao Molho', 'Salmão' ];

function buscarItens(e) {
    const res = document.querySelector('#resultado ul');
    res.innerHTML = ''; // limpa os resultados

    const busca = e.target.value.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}/ug, ''); // o que foi digitado e deve ser buscado (removendo os acentos)

    // *** Aqui: não tem mais a flag g ***
    const regex = new RegExp(busca.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'i');

    for (const item of itens) { // para cada item do menu
        const text = item.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}/ug, '');
        const li = document.createElement('li'); // cria o elemento que terá o texto com highlight
        // *** Aqui: trocar matchAll por match e não usar for ***
        const match = text.match(regex);
        if (match) {
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.slice(0, match.index))); // texto antes da palavra encontrada

            const i = match.index + busca.length;
            let strong = document.createElement('strong');
            strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.slice(match.index, i))); // palavra destacada (a "busca")
            li.appendChild(strong);

            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.slice(i))); // texto depois da palavra
            res.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}

// cada vez que digitar algo no input, faz a busca
document.querySelector('#busca').addEventListener('input', buscarItens);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="busca">

<div id="resultado">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

Outro ponto é que não foi dado detalhes do HTML, então assumi que seria uma lista (`ul`), por isso cada resultado da busca ficou em um `li`. De qualquer forma, não é difícil adaptar para outros casos, pois a lógica seria a mesma (texto antes, texto da busca dentro de `strong`, texto depois).

Answer (score 0):

### A Ideia

Para pegar todas as `substring` de uma `string` que respeitam um certo padrão e inserir a tag `<strong></strong>` entre os índices que aparecem tal padrão, onde padrão não é *[case sensitive](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive)* e ignora acentuação, devemos transformar o conteúdo dessa `string` deixando ela em caixa baixa e tirar sua acentuação, e depois achar os índices que batem com o padrão e então inserir `<strong></strong>` entre `índice` e `indice+size_padrao`.

Como você já conseguiu achar o padrão e inserir a tag `<strong></strong>`, irei explicar como consegui deixar a `string` em caixa baixa e retirar sua acentuação

### Deixando em caixa baixa, e retirando a acentuação

Para transformar uma string em caixa baixa, é simples, apenas temos que usar a função `toLowerCase()`. Agora só falta retirar a acentuação.

Na língua portuguesa temos acentos nas letras: *a, e, i, o, u, c*. Logo se criarmos uma [expressão regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) para achar cada uma dessa letras acentuadas, e substituirmos pela letra sem acento, então teremos a `string` sem acentuação.

```
// Regex para pegar acentos
var ACENTO_REGEX = {
  'a': /[\xE0-\xE6]/g,
  'e': /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
  'i': /[\xEC-\xEF]/g,
  'o': /[\xF2-\xF6]/g,
  'u': /[\xF9-\xFC]/g,
  'c': /\xE7/g
}

// Retira acento e deixa em minúsculo
function padronizaStr(str) {
  // Deixa em minúsculo
  str = str.toLowerCase();

  // Retira os acentos
  for(var re in ACENTO_REGEX) {
    str = str.replace(ACENTO_REGEX[re], re)
  }

  return str;
}
```

### Exemplo

Criei uma lista para demonstrar como seria, mas você pode alterar e colocar da forma que resolva o seu problema usando a mesma ideia.

OBS.: Usei uma variável chamada `padrao` como se já tivesse o valor do campo nela, apenas como exemplo.

```js
// Regex para pegar acentos
var ACENTO_REGEX = {
  'a': /[\xE0-\xE6]/g,
  'e': /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
  'i': /[\xEC-\xEF]/g,
  'o': /[\xF2-\xF6]/g,
  'u': /[\xF9-\xFC]/g,
  'c': /\xE7/g
}

// Tamanho de <strong></strong>
var TAG_SIZE = '<strong></strong>'.length;

// Busca os valores em <li>, a partir de <ul>
function liValues(ulNodes) {
  var liArr = [];
  
  ulNodes.forEach(function(li) { 
    if(li.innerText)
      liArr.push(li.innerText);
  });
  
  return liArr;
}

// Retira acento e deixa em minúsculo
function padronizaStr(str) {
  // Deixa em minúsculo
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  
  // Retira os acentos
  for(var re in ACENTO_REGEX) {
    str = str.replace(ACENTO_REGEX[re], re)
  }
  
  return str;
}

// Altera a lista
function alteraLista(ul, arrLi) {
  // Remove todos os <li> de <ul>
  ul.empty();
  
  // Adiciona novos <li>
  arrLi.forEach(function(li) {
    ul.append(`<li>${li}</li>`);
  });
}

function aplicaAlteracao() {
  var ulNodes = $('ul')[0].childNodes;
  var liArr = liValues(ulNodes);
  
  var padrao = "ao";
  padrao = padronizaStr(padrao);
  
  liArr = liArr.map(function(str) {
    // Vamos usar li, para não perdermos o valor de str
    li = str;
    
    // Deixa todos os valores com o padrão
    // Minúsculo e sem acentos
    li = padronizaStr(li);
    
    // Acha os indices que dão Match com o padrão
    var idxs = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\(' + padrao + ')', 'ig');
    
    while ((match = re.exec(li)) != null) {
      idxs.push(match.index);
    }
    
    idxs.forEach(function(val, idx) {
      var arr = str.split('');
      
      // Inserindo <strong></strong>
      arr.splice(val+(idx*TAG_SIZE), 0, '<strong>');
      arr.splice(val+padrao.length+1+(idx*TAG_SIZE), 0, '</strong>') 

      str = arr.join('');
    });
    
    return str;
  });
  
  alteraLista($('ul'), liArr)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Arroz</li>
  <li>Batata ao Cheff</li>
  <li>Macarrão ao Molho</li>
  <li>Salmão</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="aplicaAlteracao()">
  Altera!
</button>
```